# Difference between fgetcsv and fgets & speed difference

Tags: php, fgets, fgetcsv

I was toying around with reading text files trying to get the fastest possible way to read the files and put them into a array line by line.

Some of the files I'm using are .csv files and a few are .txt files. When I started I found a example to read csv files so I started using it but I quickly found out that fgets is significantly faster. The fgetcsvValues is the first one I created and the fgetsValues the second/faster one.

I input the files through the first parameter $chars as an array. So for example this would be a array that I use

```
$dictionaryfiles = array(
    'dictionaries/Dutch.csv'
    ,'dictionaries/English.txt);
```

The problem I'm having is that the first character of each line turns into a NULL if I use the fgetsValues function I created. Is this caused by the .csv file type or am I simply doing something wrong?

The two function aren't completely the same because I read that going through a array using FOR instead of FOREACH is faster/uses less memory but besides that they are pretty much the same.

The substr function is used to cut off the last bit of text at every line. A example of a word would be this:  "Hello/5". The first part is the word and the / is used as a separator to display the amount of characters.

And finally I use array_unique to remove any duplicate words

```
function fgetValues($chars){
    $multilines = array();
    $c = count($chars);
    for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
        $actualloc = 'data/'.$chars[$i].'';
        $file = fopen($actualloc, 'r');
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== FALSE ) {
            $line[0] = trim(substr($line[0], 0, strpos($line[0], "/")));
            array_push($multilines, $line);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    $multilines = array_unique($multilines,SORT_REGULAR);
    return $multilines;  
}

function fgetcsvValues($chars){
    $resultlines = array();
    foreach($chars as $single){
        $actualloc = 'data/'.$single.'';
        $file = fopen($actualloc, 'r');
        while(($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
            $line[0] = substr($line[0], 0, strpos($line[0], "/"));
            array_push($resultlines, $line);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    $resultlines = array_unique($resultlines,SORT_REGULAR);
    return $resultlines;  
}
```

What is causing the first characters to become NULL values? And how could I improve either of the functions to read the text files faster or better?

Comment: An approach that's oftentimes measurably quicker is `array_map("str_getcsv", file("fn.csv"))` - which reads in the file *at once*, but splits up CSV columns *per PHP core* loop. (May require post-processing empty lines/columns etc. however.)